# React native for android run very slow when not enable "Debug JS"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing an app using react native, I use some code base for ios and android, the ios version run smoothly.

But the android version run very slowly. the weird thing is:

When I shake the phone, and click "Debug JS" to enable debug in chrome feature, it run faster, anyone have a clue about the reason?

Answer (score 30):

Sometimes, one or more than one active `console.log()` lines cause this issue. 
`console.log` lines should be searched and deleted if they exist.

Also in production, [babel-plugin-transform-remove-console](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-console-log-statements) can be used to clear all console.* methods automatically.

Comment: Are you using redux-logger by any chance? I had similar issues related to console.log performances (as efkan said). Check out this thread on GitHub: https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger/issues/32

Comment: It was the logger in my case, which is actually not necessary if using the remote redux dev tools

Comment: Sneaky logs. More specifically, if you are depending on Redux and using the redux-logger middleware, ensure that this middleware runs only in dev. redux-logger will log every single action dispatched on your reducer.

Answer (score 10):

The reason for different execution speeds of javascript code when running in debug mode and without is that when you are in debug mode, in order to enable the debugging experience React Native executes the code in the Chrome browser on your computer, and the results of the execution are bridged onto the device.

Outside of the debug mode, the code is executed in the JavaScriptCore engine on the device itself.

That said, I cannot explain why the execution is so slow on the device. Are you perhaps running on an low-powered device, or an emulator with limited allocated memory?

Comment: I am getting this slowness on device too, when I am remote debugging it is fine, which is un-explainable by me. After Nov 2015, do you have any new ideas? (btw love your redux-offline!)

Answer (score 7):

React Native app does run slower on Android. But the performance is not real during your development. You can build a release version to check the real performance, release version is much faster than dev version.

There are also some bad codes which can make your app slow. Like `console.log()`, it does slow the app during development. Avoid unnecessary re-render the view, don't use arrow function and `.bind` in `render`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on IOS device (ipad4, ios10). I don't use redux-logger and removed all console.log, still don't know what makes the app so slow. It takes 2s to swich between tabs.

> "react-native": "0.41.2",
>   "react": "15.4.2",
>   "native-base": "^2.0.10",

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old topic but suffered the same problem. I applied the above solutions but the problem still presisted. Later I found out that problem caused by a emulated USB storage device rather than mounted as a USB disk. Because when you upload signed Apk file and install the appllication from this file it causes problems and  gives write error e.g. hiddenly but don't gives error messages much. I hope changing from emulated storage device to mounted as a trivial disk helps who suffer the same problem like me.