# React Native hangs when I create a child component

Tags: react-native

Sorry for the dummy question, but I'm really stuck.

I created a very simple react-native app using [these instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

Then I changed App.js to be

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Button, View } from 'react-native';

class RootView extends React.Component {    
    state = {
        showFoo: false,
    }

    showFoo = () => {
        this.setState({showFoo: true})

    }

    renderFoo = () => {
        if (this.state.showFoo) {
            console.log("at 4");
            const item  = <View  />;   /// BOOM!
            console.log('at 5', item);
            return item;
        }
        return null;
    }

    render = () => {
        const renderFoo = this.renderFoo();

        return (
            <View>
                    <Button title="Press Me" onPress={this.showFoo} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default RootView;
```

Now, if I launch it using the Expo client on my Android 6.0.1. and I press "Press Me" button, it hangs and doesn't respond to back button.

In adb logcat, I can see "at 4", but never "at 5". It is like it stucks at "BOOM!" line for some reason (a dead lock?).

Wondering if I'm doing something wrong? My apologies again, but I have already spent a fair amount of time on this, would really appreciate any clue. Also, how could I debug things like that one?

Versions of react dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2"
  }
}
```

(Please let me know if you feel the question needs more details in the comments, I'm happy to update it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after hours of investigation...

As it appears, the problem was this line:

```
 console.log('at 5', item);
```

It hasn't actually stuck. If I waited for 5+ seconds, the app proceeded. Seems like logging a react component is a very expensive operation.

Same problem I had when I was trying to log some lambda function.

**TLDR: don't log complex objects!!!!**

[React native for android run very slow when not enable "Debug JS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563119/react-native-for-android-run-very-slow-when-not-enable-debug-js)

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-consolelog-statements

Answer (score 0):

You should either use

```
<Button title="Press Me" onPress={this.showFoo.bind(this)}/>
```

or use

```
<Button title="Press Me" onPres{()=>this.showFoo()}/>
```

and also call `this.renderFoo();` inside render method, with this syntax

```
{this.renderFoo()}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way he construction the onPress call. No binding needed if `showFoo` is written in arrow function syntax

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/S11z2EfyQ) to show you the solution.

The problem is with your `render` method

```
render = () => {
    const renderFoo = this.renderFoo();

    return (
        <View>
                <Button title="Press Me" onPress={this.showFoo} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Specifically `const renderFoo = this.renderFoo();`. For this line of code, you only execute the `renderFoo` method and store it into `renderFoo` variable, and it's not within the return portion. In other words the `<View />` returned by `renderFoo` will not show on the screen.

The fix is by the below code

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
            <Button title="Press Me" onPress={this.showFoo} />
            {this.renderFoo()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Isaac. Yep, this is understood. However, my question is a bit of a different thing: why does it blocks at "at 4" line and never gets to "at 5"? Also, why the back button stops responding?

Comment: I've refactored the code again on the same snack. It you try it out again, you will noticed that line 5 is logged too.

Comment: Just that the `<View />` not being render on screen